# Unsure what set this bag of small tan and grey elements goes to

Tags: set-identification

I found this bag and I'm not sure what set it goes to.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The large number of tan 1x1 bricks with studs on adjacent sides means this can only be one of a very [small number of sets](https://rebrickable.com/parts/26604/brick-special-1-x-1-with-studs-on-2-adjacent-sides/19/). The other parts make it appear that this is a bag from [Assembly Square (10255)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/10255-1/assembly-square/):

[image: Set photo]